# Enable phone call functionality on change event (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, href, phone-call, tel

I'm trying to enable the phone call functionality on change event (HTML `<select>` tag) so as to reference the appropriate `"tel:"` value.

I run a test on **Android** *(both version **2.2** and **4.0**)*, using the default browser: I did not get the desired effect.

Below is my code:

HTML

```
<select class="call-us-options">
    <option value="">Select a branch:</option>
    <option value="branch-a">Branch A</option>
    <option value="branch-b">Branch B</option>
    <option value="branch-c">Branch C</option>
</select>
<a class="phone branch-a" href="tel:(22) 2222-222" title="Branch A">Branch A</a>
<a class="phone branch-b" href="tel:(33) 3333-3333" title="Branch B">Branch B</a>
<a class="phone branch-c" href="tel:(44) 4444-4444" title="Branch C">Branch C</a>
```

jQuery

```
$('.call-us-options').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val()) {
        alert($('.'+$(this).val()).html());
        $('.'+$(this).val()).trigger('click');
    }
});​
```

Here's JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CZ3WF/1/

Is there any effective way to achieve that?

Comment: Do you have functions associated to your `a` elements that will register the click event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try `window.location = "tel:(44) 4444-4444"` (whatever the number is in the anchor corresponding to the selectIndex) with the `onChange` event for `<select>`?

### Edit:

`click()` will only trigger javascript event handlers and will not actually go to that URL. Im not sure if this would work but can you try `window.location` once.

Comment: @FredWuerges thanks for giving working example. As very few people mark accepted by giving working example.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.call-us-options').on('change', function() {

        window.location.href = $('.'+$(this).val()).attr('href');

});
```