# Trigger phone call with Javascript

Tags: javascript, tel

I would like to trigger a `tel:12345` HREF using only Javascript, not with an anchor. I simply want to grab the value of an input field and use JS to prompt the user to call the number typed in. My trigger will be a button located next to the field.

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Tadaaaaa! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: Some punk is going to put 911 in that input field.

Comment: Or worse, some botnet will hammer it on behalf of all it's owned users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Phone call with mobile device (href="tel:") and javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385143/html-phone-call-with-mobile-device-href-tel-and-javascript)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use:

```
window.open('tel:12345');
```

Comment: Is that best solution or `window.location.href='tel:12345';` , which one is better ?

Comment: @adrianTNT I like your solution better because it doesn't open a new window or tab. It just makes the call from the current window.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">
Call
</button>

function myFunction(){
var a = document.getElementById('input').value;
window.location.href = 'tel:' + a;
}
You can also view the live version on my website:
https://www.theharnishes.com/phone.html

Here we make a button and assign a function to it that bassically select the input, get the value, and the window.location.href will have the value of the input and it'll sent the url to call any number.
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

Js call making is very simple.
Using our : onclick function ,   Location , and tel
We can do this in any tag,
window . location ('tel:number')

Click  me to call 199

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.