# How to make iPhone call

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, call

How can i make my iPhone call by pressing some element on web-page?
I need something like

> $("#container").click(function() { /*Making a call*/ });

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger phone call with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781772/trigger-phone-call-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This should work (not tested):

```
$("#container").click(function() {
    window.location.href("tel://15415551234");
});
```